# edit text file and save text file with edits

Tags: vb.net

ok so the easiest way i can break down what im trying to do is this, I have a text file with 5 words on it (maybe more in the future), one line has 3 words and one line has 2 words, all words separated by spaces

I'm trying to load the words in the text file into a listbox BUT I only want one word per line in the list box.

i don't have any sample code as I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

the text file looks like:

`account1      account2     account3`
`account4      account5`

I want it to look like(one word per line):

```
account1 
account2 
account3 
account4 
account
```

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
         Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")             ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)         
    Dim fw As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")         
    For Each itm As Object In Me.ListBox1.Items             
        fw.WriteLine(itm.ToString)         
    Next         
    fw.Close()
        fw.Dispose()
        fw = Nothing
        For Each line In lines             
        String.Split()         
    Next     
End Sub
```

any help is greatly appreciated I have been trying to figure this out for about 4 hours :'(

final working code below for those interested

```
Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt").Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(" ", vbCr).Split(vbCr, options:=StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

        ' Read
        'TextBox1.Multiline = True
        ListBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")


        'Write
        'IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt", ListBox1.Text)
        Dim SW As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")
        For Each S As String In ListBox1.Items
            SW.WriteLine(S)
        Next
        SW.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: `IO.File.ReadAllLines()` --> `For Each line in lines` --> `String.Split()`.

Comment: `Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim lines As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(lines)
        Dim fw As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")
        For Each itm As Object In Me.ListBox1.Items
            fw.WriteLine(itm.ToString)
        Next
        fw.Close()
        fw.Dispose()
        fw = Nothing
        For Each line In lines
            String.Split()
        Next
    End Sub`
this is what I currently have

Comment: cant seem to figure out how to format on here LUL

Comment: You should [edit] the question and add your code there. Use the `{}` button to put the code in a code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\File.txt").Replace(vbLf, "").Replace(" ", vbCr).Split(vbCr, options:=StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

    ' Read
    TextBox1.Multiline = True
    TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\File.txt")


    'Write
    IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\File.txt", TextBox1.Text)
```

Comment: that works to display in the listbox but doesn't work to edit the textfile

Comment: Add textbox to your form and have multiline = true

        ' Read
        TextBox1.Multiline = True
        TextBox1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\File.txt")


        'Write
        IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\File.txt", TextBox1.Text)

Comment: amended code still doesnt write to the file

Comment: achieved success with:
{
        Dim SW As IO.StreamWriter = IO.File.CreateText("C:\Scrape\textfile.txt")
        For Each S As String In ListBox1.Items
            SW.WriteLine(S)
        Next
        SW.Close()
}

Answer (score 0):

```
For editing :
 Try
     Dim thefile As String = "C:\con_ip.txt" 'Put your path
     Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\con_ip.txt")
     lines(Put which line to edit) = "Put the Value to edit "
     System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(thefile, lines)
 Catch ex As Exception

 End Try
```